# How do I use geopy (or a geopy-like framework) to access local OSM planet data?

Tags: python, openstreetmap, geopy

Suppose I download data from OSM planet:
https://planet.openstreetmap.org/

and would like to use geopy to make calls to my now local data rather than to the Nominatim framework. In other words, I would like to use OSM planet to implement a local version of this code:

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

geolocator = Nominatim()
locationstr = "New York City"
location = geolocator.geocode(locationstr,timeout=None)
location2 = geolocator.reverse(str(location.latitude) + ", " + str(location.longitude), language='en', timeout = None)
```

How do I go about this?